# Download overview of Gmail inbox to text file

Tags: gmail

How can I approach this? Could you help me?

The format of the text file is not very important. An possible format would be:

```
Email 1;Involved contact(s);Subject and preview;Date or time 
Email 2;Involved contact(s);Subject and preview;Date or time 
...
```

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: It looks like you haven't been around for a few days, so here are some suggestions since I don't know your OS:
Windows - Try [GetMail](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/getmail.html).  For Linux, try [Pine](http://www.washington.edu/pine/), [Elm](http://www.elmme-mailer.org/), or [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)

Comment: Many thanks and apologies for the slow response. I am on Windows. GetMail looks like a useful tool and I will certainly play with it when I find some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GMail offers a RSS feed](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13474) with the basic details of each mail.

I used this [XSL file](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1162) to transform that feed to a more readable format
[image]

You can tweak the XSL to generate the feed information in a format that you like.

Comment: +1 for using RSS and XSLT. Definitely a flexible solution!

Comment: I believe the RSS feed only includes unread emails. Hopefully marking a message as unread will put it back on the feed.

Comment: Looks promising. Could you kindly provide some guidance as to how to edit the XSL code to work with the Gmail Atom Feed? (I am new to web technologies.) Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could enable POP downloading and move/copy your inbox to a local client like Thunderbird.  From there the messages will be stored in a flat file that you can access.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Context.IO](http://context.io), it will let you script that sort of things. If you have any questions or problems, let us know http://support.context.io, we'll be happy to help.